# Order by COUNT per value

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by

I have a table which stores IDs and the city where the store is located.

I want to list all the stores starting with the stores that are in the city where there are the most stores.

TABLE

```
ID CITY
1  NYC
2  BOS
3  BOS
4  NYC
5  NYC
```

The output I want is the following since I have the most stores in NYC, I want all the NYC location to be listed first.

```
1  NYC
4  NYC
5  NYC
2  BOS
3  BOS
```

Comment: Exact Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187033/mysql-order-by-number-of-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-column-of-mysql-table?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 80):

```
SELECT count(City), City
FROM table
GROUP BY City
ORDER BY count(City);
```

OR

```
SELECT count(City) as count, City
FROM table
GROUP BY City
ORDER BY count;
```

Ahh, sorry, I was misinterpreting your question. I believe Peter Langs answer was the correct one.

Comment: Maybe I'm not doing it right but when I use "group by" instead of listing each individual store it will only list 1 store for NYC and 1 store for BOS. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Enkay: That's exactly what group by does. It condenses identical entries.

Comment: Yea but my stores are not identical, I have 3 different stores in NYC with a unique store ID. I need to list each individual store. I just want them ordered by the city with the highest number of stores.

Comment: If you add Id to the 'GROUP BY' it will list all stroes

Answer (score 34):

This one calculates the count in a separate query, joins it and orders by that count ([SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/018a52/2)):

```
SELECT c.id, c.city
FROM cities c
JOIN ( SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM cities
       GROUP BY city
     ) c2 ON ( c2.city = c.city )
ORDER BY c2.cnt DESC;
```

Comment: how would you be able to add WHERE to this?

Comment: @jdwee: You would add it before the `ORDER BY` clause. If it should also reflect on the COUNT, then you would either have to repeat it within the subquery, or better: use a [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html). If this does not help, please post a separate question instead.

Answer (score 6):

This solution is not a very optimal one so if your table is very large it will take some time to execute but it does what you are asking.

```
 select c.city, c.id, 
      (select count(*) as cnt from city c2 
       where c2.city = c.city) as order_col
 from city c
 order by order_col desc
```

That is, for each city that you come across you are counting the number of times that that city occurs in the database.

Disclaimer: This gives what you are asking for but I would not recommend it for production environments where the number of rows will grow too large.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `FirstAddressLine4`, count(*) AS `Count` 
FROM `leads` 
WHERE `Status`='Yes'
AND `broker_id`='0'
GROUPBY `FirstAddressLine4` 
ORDERBY `Count` DESC 
LIMIT 0, 8
```