# Geting results from 2 database tables

Tags: php, mysql

i need some help getting the most commented post.
There are 2 tables, one have the posts web_content and the other table have the comments web_jcomments.

I need to get the most commented post and the number of comments.
The web_content.ID = web_jcomments.object_id.
The datebase is in MYSQL.

Please can some one help with the SQL code?
Thank you for reading

Comment: What RDBMS? (I assume MySQL given the php tag?)

Comment: this a custom system? I'd suggest adding a `num_comments` field to the main post table that you increment each time you do an insert to the comments table. otherwise reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283305/mysql-order-by-count

Comment: i cant add any row. i only need to join this table and order the posts by comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
       wc.ID,
       wj.Total
FROM web_content as wc
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT 
                object_id,
                count(object_id)   as Total 
) as  wj on wc.ID = wj.object_id
ORDER BY wi.Total DESC
```

Comment: Add LIMIT 1 at the end if you want just the top one.

Answer (score 0):

long time since I've written MySQL..

something like:

```
SELECT  
        web_content.ID, 
        COUNT(*) 
FROM web_content.ID 
LEFT JOIN web_jcomments ON (web_content.ID = web_jcomments.object_id)
```