# how can convert this sql statment to laravel orm?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

```
SELECT book_id, COUNT(*)
FROM book
GROUP BY book_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

how can convert this sql statment to Laravel ORM ?

**Editing :**

this sql statement work in MYSQL but not int laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the job:

```
$result = Book::select(array('book_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count')))
            ->groupBy('book_id')
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(*)'), 'desc')
            ->get();
```

To test/debug your query, add this before it:

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time) {
    var_dump($sql);
    var_dump($bindings);
});
```

Or send it to log:

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time) {
    var_dump($sql);
    var_dump($bindings);
});
```

This code will plot the builded query into your browser page, like this:

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time) {
    Log::info($sql);
    Log::info($bindings);
});
```

And to look at your log:

```
php artisan tail
```

Comment: can this converted to ORM ?

Comment: This is Eloquent ORM.

Comment: i try now to use this, but show me this error "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'COUNT(*)' "

Comment: I just edited it, for Laravel 4 and added a way for you to debug it. I also tested that query here in my end using the users table and it worked fine.

Comment: The problem is, can your database server order by `count(*)`? Did you ran that query in your database server before? This error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'COUNT(*)'` looks like your databas server not understanting it as a column.

Comment: issue in count, "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'count' "

Comment: i run this sql statment in my mysql server and work perfect but in a=laravel show me this error !

Comment: Did you used DB::listen() to get the raw query?

Comment: And what was the outcome?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'count(*)'

Comment: you can sir try to use count in you laravel for any table, this issue will also showed

Comment: sorry for my English language

Comment: DB::listen() will not give you an error, before this error you should see something else. Just edited with a way to send the raw query to the log.

Comment: Antonio Carlos Ribeiro, can you use this code in your laravel with mysql using count ? and you will see same error

Comment: This is my test code: http://puu.sh/7ONL5.png. This is the result I see in browser: http://puu.sh/7ONN4.png. No error. I'm using postgresql database.

Comment: According to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283305/mysql-order-by-count. It should work for you too. But I asked many times for you to get the raw query, you MUST get the query Laravel generates for you and test in your database. This is done with DB::listen() and I have you two options to use it. Have you at least tried get the the generated query?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'count(*)' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `books` group by `book_id` order by `count(*)` desc)

Comment: now this work, i don't why didn't work before but now working. thanks you very mush