# mysql: ORDER BY number of occurrences of an element in a column of mysql table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Can someone please help me to 'ORDER' a mysql table according to the no. of occurrences of a string in one of the columns of same table.

I want to rearrange the table according to the number of times a location has occurred.

*Please see the example below:*

```
id    name       location
--    -----      --------
1     Mark       US
2     Mike       US
3     Paul       Australia
4     Pranshu    India
5     Pranav     India
6     John       Canada
7     Rishab     India
```

*Expected result:*

```
id    name       location
--    -----      --------
4     Pranshu    India
5     Pranav     India
7     Rishab     India
1     Mark       US
2     Mike       US
3     Paul       Australia
6     John       Canada
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(location) AS count FROM `tablename` GROUP BY `location` ORDER BY count DESC;
```

But it showed me the following result **omitting the repeating occurrence** of location:

```
id    name       location
--    -----      --------
4     Pranshu    India
1     Mark       US
3     Paul       Australia
6     John       Canada
```

Comment: It's rare that the thing one counts is also the thing one groups by!

Comment: The answer from @MindStalker is exactly what you need right now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283305/mysql-order-by-count

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN (SELECT location, COUNT(*) total FROM my_table GROUP BY location) y
    ON y.location = x.location
 ORDER 
    BY total DESC
     , id;
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.