# MySQL: Count then sort by the count total

Tags: mysql

I know other posts talk about this, but I haven't been able to apply anything to this situation.

This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ccParts, ccChild, ccFamily
WHERE parGC = '26' AND 
  parChild = chiId AND 
  chiFamily = famId 
ORDER BY famName, chiName
```

What I need to do is see the total number of ccParts with the same ccFamily in the results. Then, sort by the total.

Comment: Could you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it?

Comment: First of all you should not use SELECT * on three different tables but select only the field you need. Then, could you show us the structure of the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is close to what you want:

```
SELECT f.famId, f.famName, pc.parCount
FROM (
    SELECT c.chiFamily AS famId, count(*) AS parCount
    FROM 
      ccParts p
      JOIN ccChild c ON p.parChild = c.chiId
    WHERE p.parGC ='26' 
    GROUP BY c.chiFamily
  ) pc
  JOIN ccFamily f ON f.famId = pc.famId
ORDER BY pc.parCount
```

The inline view (between the parentheses) is the headliner: it does your grouping and counting.  Note that you do not need to join table `ccFamily` there to group by family, as table `ccChild` already carries the family information.  If you don't need the family name (i.e. if its ID were sufficient), then you can stick with the inline view alone, and there `ORDER BY count(*)`.  The outer query just associates family name with the results.

Additionally, MySQL provides a **non-standard** mechanism by which you could combine the outer query with the inline view, but in this case it doesn't help much with either clarity or concision.  The query I provided should be accepted by any SQL implementation, and it's to your advantage to learn such syntax and approaches first.

Answer (score 1):

In the `SELECT`, add something like `count(ccParts) as count` then `ORDER BY count` instead? Not sure about the structure of your tables so you might need to improvise.

Comment: Ok, I think I need to use a group, so that I'm counting ccParts with the same ccFamily.?

Comment: You will need to show some sample data. And yes, I think that a `GROUP BY` is necessary.

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283305/mysql-order-by-count