# Find the most frequent value and order by it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

```
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| being_followed        | follower               |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| Bob Dylan             |                      B |
| Bob Dylan             |                      A |
| Sam Cooke             |                      X |
| The Beatles           |                      Y |
| Bob Dylan             |                      M |
| Sam Cooke             |                      N |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

Now, I want to find which is the most occurring value in `being_followed` and then order by it.
  It should look somewhat like -

```
Bob Dylan - 3
Sam Cooke - 2
The Beatles - 1
```

Please don't mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: top 2000? (list from the Netherlands)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order by COUNT per value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283305/order-by-count-per-value)

Answer (score 1):

Try below :

```
select being_followed , count(1) as count
from table
group by being_followed 
order by count desc ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
select being_followed,count(*) total_followers
from table
group by being_followed
order by total_followers desc
```

Comment: `Follower` should not be in `group by`. It will not give proper result. Please validate .

Comment: Also, `order by` should be based on `count` as per question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT being_followed , count(being_followed )as counter FROM `table_Name` GROUP BY being_followed ORDER BY counter DESC
```

You will get result what you want.Here using group by you will get unique value and using count you will get counter of same being_followed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT being_followed,COUNT(*) AS follower 
FROM tablename GROUP BY being_followed ORDER BY follower DESC;
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| being_followed        | follower               |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| Bob Dylan             |                      3 |
| Sam Cooke             |                      2 |
| The Beatles           |                      1 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT being_followed,COUNT(1) count_followers
FROM table
GROUP BY being_followed
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC;
```

Get count of being_followed and also order by high to low bases(descending order)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this:

```
select being_followed, count(*) follower
from TableName
group by being_followed
order by follower desc
```

It's working fine.