# Ordering rows after being fetched

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a video watching service, and I'm having some issues ordering videos based on their views. You see, the video src's, their thumbnails, and other information are on one databases, and the recorded views are on another.

The table containing the video information looks like this:

[image]

and the table containing the view count looks like this:

[image]

So, in a nutshell, the way views are calculated, is by counting the number of rows with the video id in the `views` database.

Well.. What I would like to do, is order videos based on their views. I'm having some trouble doing this, as I can't just use `$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 15";`

I'm not sure how to do this, but that is the SQL I was using before I moved the view counter from the `video` database.

Here's the PHP I'm using to display the video's:

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);} 

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 15";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo '<a href="https://www.example.com/watch?v=' . $row["url"] . '">
                 <div class="twinkieman_video-block_small_c">
                     <div class="twinkieman_video-block_small_inner">
                         <div class="twinkieman_video-block_small_header">
                             <img src="' . $row["thumbnail"] . '" alt="' . $row["title"] . '" class="twinkieman_video-block_small_image" />
                         </div>

                         <div class="twinkieman_video-block_small_title">
                             <span>' . $row["title"] . '</span>
                         </div>

                         <div class="twinkieman_video-block_small_uploader">Uploaded by <a href="' . $server . '/user/' . strtolower(getUser($row["postedby"], "name")) . '" class="twinkieman_video-block_small_uploader_name"><span>' . getUser($row["postedby"], "name") . '</span></a></div>
                          <div class="twinkieman_video-block_small_views"><span>' . getViews($row["videoid"]) . ' views</span></div>
                          <div class="twinkieman_video-block_small_posted"><span>' . time_elapsed_string('@' . $row["posted"]) . '</span></div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </a>';
         }
     } $conn->close();
 ?>
```

***Please Note:*** There is a `views` column in the `videos` database because thats what I was using to count views before. I am no longer using this, so the `views` column is now useless.

Comment: does this view table contain on e recors per vedio or multiple ?

Comment: It's one record per view. So, every time someone views a video, it adds a new record for their ip address with the id of the video they viewed

Comment: in a nutshell: `select col1, colx from videos left join views on ... group by col1, colx order by count(*) desc`

Comment: The php code is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: I don't know how I can apply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283305/order-by-count-per-value's solution to my case.. I've never worked with any of that stuff before..

Comment: I tried it.. I used this: `$sql = "SELECT videos.videoid, videos.title, videos.url, videos.thumbnail, videos.postedby, videos.posted, views.videoid FROM videos INNER JOIN views ON videos.videoid=views.videoid ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 15";`. It works.. ish.. but if the video has 2 views, it echo's the block twice.. If it has 3 views, it echo's it 3 times.. and so on. How can I fix this?

Comment: Nevermind.. It doesn't work

Comment: Still struggling? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I've provided all of my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work out quite easily if you do your grouping and counting in a subquery like

```
SELECT videoid, title, url, thumbnail, 
postedby, posted, cnt
FROM videos
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT videoid vid,COUNT(*) cnt
 FROM views
 GROUP BY videoid) s ON vid=videoid
ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 15
```

Check out the little Demo here: http://rextester.com/XDQ58442

Comment: You are an absolute legend! I was quickly losing hope, as everyone looked to be against me hahah.. Thank you so much! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Unnecessary to have a subquery in this case, inner join will cause videos with 0 views to drop from the resultset.

Comment: Well, you are right, it is not *necessary*, but maybe convenient, as *with it* the query can be written without having to use table aliases in front of all the columns. And, yes, if you also want the rows without any view entries listed, feel free to change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`. I sincerely hope I have not upset this perfect Stackoverflow universe to much by having been so bold as to answer a "closed" question...