# How to find most duplicate value in a table?

Tags: mysql

The question basically means is how can we find duplicate values in a row?
Example: I am making a blog website and in that, I want to display trending tags...

For this I created 2 tables:

1. blog
2. tag

in the blog table, my blog record is there, and in the tag table there are two columns

1. id (PRIMARY)
2. name
3. blog_id

[image: tag table]

I want to display the top repeating names that come in the tag table.
So, can you please just tell me what is the solution about it?

Like here Java repeats most time in the table.
So, I just want the output to be like:

1. JAVA
2. Database
3. PHP

Comment: Search about SQL HAVING statement, combined with ORDER BY. Does It help you?

Comment: Ok. Let me check if it's working... But how can I use ORDER BY in that statement I don't want to recognize it alphabatically

Comment: You probably just want to `ORDER BY` a `COUNT()` column, while you do a `GROUP BY` the name column. Just check this other SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283305/order-by-count-per-value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order by COUNT per value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283305/order-by-count-per-value)

Comment: Order BY count(column)

Comment: Just wait. Let me check whether this post solves my query or not?

Comment: Yes, it solves my question but it is quite different from other post questions. Wait for a while I will post answer of this question also..

Comment: To solve this problem just run this query : 

In my case this is :
`SELECT count(name), name FROM `tag` GROUP BY name ORDER BY count(name) DESC`

WHERE `name` is a column and `tag` is the table name